# How can I change a field value when SharePoint workflow is cancelled?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-workflow

I am using SharePoint 2010 workflow template to create approval workflow for my organization. One thing I am stuck at is how to update a field when the users cancel the workflow. It does not seems like there is any workflow parameter that capture the workflow status when it is cancelled by user.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Workflow History List:

http://[servername]/[sitename]/lists/Workflow%20History

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this is **not** a link-only answer. It is not a link, it shows how a URL is formed on given server and site. Voting "Looks OK".